# Scope of SqlDataConnection variable with SQL Type Provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, f#, type-providers

Using the SQL type provider in FSharp.Data with MSFT SQL Server, I declare the type:

```
type dbSchema = FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=DESKTOP-5\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;">
```

outside of any module, along with most of my other types (following a suggestion to declare types outside of modules to avoid nested classes). I really wouldn't know, but assume that it's so far so good.

Where I'm wondering how to arrange things is in using the type, with eg:

```
use db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(sqlCreateTableStmt a b c)
```

My upload process goes through lists of lists and functions calling functions. And I don't know what the pros and cons are of where to declare `use db`. It could be re-done locally in each function, or "globally" outside any module, or in the first, top-level function and passed along from function to function as a parameter. Or some combination.

Hopefully that's enough of a question to be worthwhile. Right now I have a `use` declaration in each function. Not passing it ever. In some places one function declares `use db` and calls another function that declares `use db` again. I don't know if there's overhead in making or managing these connections. Or whatever else to worry about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current approach seems fine, i.e. `use` with small datacontexts. This should ensure that the context gets disposed once it goes out of scope, and at some point GC-d. Regarding the overhead you would need to benchmark. Another approach would be to pass around the context, but then you would need to make sure it doesn't get disposed before you're done. Depending on what you're doing you might set `ObjectTrackingEnabled <- false` on the context to lighten the memory load (this is less applicable for writing). Take a look at [Sqlclient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) too.

Comment: I recommend you try to keep as many of your functions as pure calculations as possible. Then you can aggregate your required reads and writes in higher level functions, and do more passing of data and less DB access. This may involve defining more types to make it clearer what data is being passed around. A side benefit is that your code will be easier to test and explore in FSI.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Database access is inherently about IO so it's not always possible (or even makes sense) to keep it pure (unless we are in Haskell, where we can spend two days on just trying to do IO). How much data passing and how DB access is needed really depends on each individual case. I'm not saying the above comment is wrong, but for example I could have said, try to do as much DB access as possible in small chunks, because the objects being written are large and put heavy strain on the GC.